Will all black holes become wormholes eventually?
Just saw a claim in a sci-pop video that when the universe will cool down and Hawking radiation will dominate, all black holes will become entangled with each other, effectively becoming wormholes. Is this true?

We don't know how black holes could possibly be entangled, given that they aren't known to be quantum particles.

Susskind does suggest that, if you fall into one entangled black hole, then you end up inside the other black hole entangled with the first one. This is exactly the route of how your tax money disappear.

Link to the video would be helpful.

@D.Halsey I think, it is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAo_NKGJGCs

Night sky is dark. It follows, that when Hawking radiation will dominate the sky, only tiny fraction of all Hawking quanta would be absorbed by other black holes. So black hole would be entangled with each other only by a tiny fraction. Even if we take ER=EPR seriously, wormhole geometries are for maximally entangled pairs of black holes.
